# Whether minor criminal record (petty theft) in Sweden affects UK visitor visa application?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, criminal-records

I am a Chinese and would like to seek help with the UK visa application.

I forgot to scan an item (11 Euro) at the supermarket in Sweden in August 2022. But I paid for the other 17 Euro items. The security called the police. And then I was accused of petty theft (ringa stöld).

According to the court decision, I was fined 230 Euro. But I had no intention of stealing, actually because of difficulty concentrating after working all night. Another reason is that the policeman's English is not good, so they misunderstood my explanation, which led to the confession showing that I pleaded guilty.

I am a PhD student and will visiting study in UK in January 2023. Recently, I prepared to apply for the UK visa (standard visitor visa： visit to study).

I would like to ask if this criminal record will affect the application. Will I be rejected, although it is a minor crime? Will Sweden's criminal record be shared with the UK?

Comment: Do you actually have a criminal record or it was just a fine ?

Comment: @Max  I don't know the exact definition of the crime. But the charges are dealt with by the court and the final decision is also made by the court.

Comment: @Max - Fines are issued by courts only after someone is convicted (found or pleaded guilty) and thus that makes a criminal record.

Answer (score 5):

A visitor application **must** be refused if a criminal conviction occurs within the last 12 months of the application under [UK Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal#:%7E:text=9.3.-,1.,9.3.):

> 9.4.4. An application for entry clearance or permission to enter under Appendix V: Visitor, or where a person is seeking entry on arrival in the UK for a stay for less than 6 months, must be refused where the applicant:
>
> [...]
>
> (b) has been convicted of a criminal offence in the UK or overseas for which they have received a non-custodial sentence, or received an out-of-court disposal that is recorded on their criminal record, unless more than 12 months have passed since the date of conviction.

For other categories, there is no mandatory refusal period of 12 months.

But in all cases, the officer has the discretionary power to refuse an application due to a previous criminal conviction regardless how long ago it was.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I apply for the student visa, do I have the chance?